# How to get list of all deleted sites using Microsoft API?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, site, api, microsoft-graph

Is there a way to get a list of all deleted sites in sharePoint using Microsoft Graph or SharePoint API? I don’t want to use powershell. I want a api. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use Get-SPODeletedSite command to get deleted sites in SharePoint Online:

```
$adminUPN="adminname@Tenant.onmicrosoft.com"
$orgName="TenantName"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential
Get-SPODeletedSite -IncludePersonalSite
```

[Get-SPODeletedSite](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-online/get-spodeletedsite?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: I don't want to use powershell. I want an API either microsoft graph or sharepoint api

Comment: @MridulSharma  Graph API have no endpoint to list deleted sites https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/directory-deleteditems-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

  Rest API is client side API, also not have such enpoint to get deleted sites.

In this case, SharePoint Online Mangement Shell is the only way to achieve it.